# Having issues with this lambda code not returning a value for all situations

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I'm working on a project that requires that I use a few Lambdas. I am trying to create one that will have two strings and an int plugged into it, and if the two strings are the same, then the int++. Here is my code:

```
DelegateName tally = (x, y, z) => { if (x == y) z++; };
```

I understand how not all code paths return a value but I am not sure what direction to go to fix it. I essentially will run this 12 times in order to add a tally to one of 12 variables if the x string is the same as the y string. It is counting the number of matching strings and adding it to the appropriate variable (the int)

Here is the code that I am trying to replace with a lambda:

```
if (cellValue.ToString().Substring(0, 1) == "1")
                {
                    variable1++;
                }
```

Was hoping to clean it up by calling tally(cellValue.ToString().SubString(0,1), 1, variable1) instead

Comment: as your `variable1` is `int`, you will pass it **"by value"**, so `z` in `tally` and `variable1` are independent and `z++` will **not** affect `variable1` value.

Comment: No code paths return a value (incrementing a variable value is not returning a value). What type is `DelegateName`?

Comment: `variable1 += cellValue.ToString().StartsWith("1") ? 1 : 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `variable1` is a `int` (a [Value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types)) so when you pass it as argument, you actually passing its value, so inside your `tally` lambda there will be **another** `int` variable `z` which is independent from `variable1`. So, when you do `z++` inside `tally`, your `variable1` is not changing.

If your `tally` is defined near `variable1` you may just use it inside your lambda:

```
var variable1 = 0;
DelegateName tally = (x, y) => { if (x == y) variable1++; };

foreach (var cellValue in cells)
     tally(cellValue.ToString().SubString(0,1), "1");
```

Another way is a [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/):

```
using System.Linq;

var variable1 = cells.Select(c => c.ToString().FirstOrDefault()).Count(c => c == '1');
// or even better (thx @RufusL)
var variable2 = cells.Count(c => c.ToString().StartsWith("1"));
```

Comment: @RufusL just see your comment and edit my answer, thanks! Almost forgot about `string.StartsWith(..)`:)

Answer (score 0):

Think of a lambda as just shorthand for a regular method. The lambda you provided:

```
(x, y, z) => { if (x == y) z++; }
```

translates to:

```
void IncrementIfEqual(string x, string y, int z)
{
    if (x == y) z++;
}
```

(Lambdas don't have a method name, so I just randomly called the method `IncrementIfEqual`). You aren't returning any value from inside the method, so the method returns void. Also, the argument `z` that you pass in gets incremented inside the method, but doesn't have any effect on the value of the original variable passed in. For example, if you called the method you wrote like this...

```
IncrementIfEqual(cellValue.ToString().Substring(0, 1), "1", variable1)
```

then variable1 would remain the same value after the call because the method incremented the argument z, which doesn't exist outside the method. You could write the method like this...

```
int IncrementIfEqual(string x, string y, int z)
{
    return (x == y) ? ++z : z;
}
```

which increments the value `z` and returns it if `x` and `y` are equal, otherwise it just returns the original value passed in. You could then call it like this...

```
variable1 = IncrementIfEqual(cellValue.ToString().Substring(0, 1), "1", variable1)
```

In that case, the lambda expression you'd want is this...

```
(x, y, z) => { return (x == y) ? ++z : z; }
```

I'm not sure what `DelegateName` is, but if it has the Invoke() method, your full usage might be something like this...

```
DelegateName tally = (x, y, z) => { if (x == y) z++; };
variable1 = tally.Invoke(cellValue.ToString().Substring(0, 1), "1", variable1)
```

Comment: `void IncrementIfEqual(x, y, z) { return (x == y) ? ++z : z; }` - you can't return from `void`

Comment: I think `DelegateName` is a name of delegate defined somewhere like this: `delegate void DelegateName(string x, string y, int z);`

Comment: @vasily.sib Good catch. I updated the methods, and you're probably right about DelegateName.